# Excel file loading in vaex

Tags: python, vaex

Is it possible to read excel directly in vaex like it do for csv? We could find from_csv function for loading csv but couldn't find a method for excel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you are loading an excel file, that means it is probably quite small. You can do it via pandas, something like `df = vaex.from_pandas(pd.read_excel('my_file.xls'))`.